# Grid based maze - robot stops at every square

Tags: arduino-ide

I need a little bit of help.

I'm working on a school project where a robot with 3 ultrasonic sensors needs to go through grid based maze (5x5) and then draw its map.

But I got stuck. I'm trying to let the robot stop close to the center of a square, let it ping the position of obstacles, write out the positions and then let it choose the next direction where to go.

I tried it with the ollowing code, but without any success.
(main part is in loop function)

```
#include <AFMotor.h>
#include <elapsedMillis.h>
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <MPU6050_tockn.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define SONAR_NUM 3
#define TRIGGER_PIN 45
#define ECHO_PIN 44
#define L_TRIG_PIN 36
#define L_ECHO_PIN 37
#define R_TRIG_PIN 30
#define R_ECHO_PIN 31
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200
#define eps 5.0
#define PING_INTERVAL 250

unsigned long pingTimer[SONAR_NUM];
unsigned int cm[SONAR_NUM];
uint8_t currentSensor = 0;

MPU6050 mpu6050(Wire);
AF_DCMotor motorL(3);
AF_DCMotor motorR(4); 

NewPing sonar[SONAR_NUM] = {   
  NewPing( R_TRIG_PIN, R_ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE ), 
  NewPing( L_TRIG_PIN, L_ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE ),
  NewPing( TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE  )
};

long timer = 0;
bool WallRight, WallLeft, WallFront,WallBack, 
     Turned180, TurnedLeft, TurnedRight; 
int Distance = 0, modulo;
// Direction 1: front, 2: right, 3: back, 4: left
int Direction = 2;      
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int dx = 1;
int dy = 0;
float Angle, NewAngle;
long TimerFront = 0;
long StopTimer = 0;

struct Array {
  bool Left;
  bool Right;
  bool Front;
  bool Back;
  int StrucDirection;
};

Array Map[5][5];

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();

  mpu6050.begin();
  mpu6050.calcGyroOffsets(true);

  motorL.setSpeed(85);
  motorR.setSpeed(80);

  pingTimer[0] = millis() + 75;
  for ( uint8_t i = 1; i < SONAR_NUM; i++ )
  {
    // Set the starting time for each sensor.
    pingTimer[i] = pingTimer[i - 1] + PING_INTERVAL;
  }

  Map[0][0].Left = true;
  Map[0][0].Right = true;
  Map[0][0].Front = false;
  Map[0][0].Back = true;
  Map[0][0].StrucDirection = 2;
}

void loop() 
{ 
  // Loop through all the sensors.
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SONAR_NUM; i++) 
  { 
    // Is it this sensor's time to ping?
    if (millis() >= pingTimer[i]) 
    {
      // Set next time this sensor will be pinged.
      pingTimer[i] += PING_INTERVAL * SONAR_NUM;  

      // Make sure previous timer is canceled before 
      // starting a new ping (insurance).
      sonar[currentSensor].timer_stop();

      // Sensor being accessed.
      currentSensor = i;
      // Make distance zero in case there's no ping echo for this sensor.
      cm[currentSensor] = 0;
      // Do the ping (processing continues, 
      // interrupt will call echoCheck to look for echo).
      sonar[currentSensor].ping_timer(echoCheck);
    }
  }

  if ( ( modulo >= 7 ) && ( modulo <= 9 ) || 
       ( cm[2] < 7 && cm[2] > 0 ) ) 
  {
    if( millis() - StopTimer >= 1000 )
    {
      motorL.run(RELEASE);
      motorR.run(RELEASE);
      //Serial.println(dx);
      //Serial.println(dy);
      if( x + dx < 5 && x + dx >= 0 && y + dy < 5 && y + dy >= 0 ) 
      {
        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy; 
      }

      Obstacles();  
    }
    DecideWhereNext();
    modulo = 0;
  }
}

void TurnLeft()
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SONAR_NUM; i++) 
    pingTimer[i] = -1;

  mpu6050.update();
  motorL.setSpeed(150);
  motorR.setSpeed(145);
  Angle = mpu6050.getAngleZ();
  NewAngle = Angle + 86.0;
  //Serial.println(Angle);
  //Serial.println(NewAngle);

  while(abs(Angle - NewAngle) > eps)
  { 
    if( millis() - timer > 50 )
    {     
        mpu6050.update();
        Angle = mpu6050.getAngleZ();
        //Serial.println(Angle);
        timer = millis();
    }
    motorR.run(FORWARD);
    motorL.run(BACKWARD);

  }

  motorL.run(RELEASE); 
  motorR.run(RELEASE);
  TurnedLeft = true;

  if(dy == 1)
  {
    dx=-1;
    dy=0;
    Direction = 4;
  }
  else if ( dy == -1 )
  {
    dx=1;
    dy=0;
    Direction = 2;
  }
  else if( dx == 1 )
  {
    dx=0;
    dy=1;
    Direction = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    dx=0;
    dy=-1;
    Direction = 3;
   }

   pingTimer[0] = millis();
   for (uint8_t i = 1; i < SONAR_NUM; i++)
     pingTimer[i] = pingTimer[i - 1] + PING_INTERVAL;
}

void TurnRight()
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SONAR_NUM; i++) 
    pingTimer[i] = -1;

  mpu6050.update();
  motorL.setSpeed(165);
  motorR.setSpeed(170);
  Angle = mpu6050.getAngleZ();
  NewAngle = Angle - 84.0;
  //Serial.println(Angle);
  //Serial.println(NewAngle);

  while( abs( Angle - NewAngle ) > eps )
  { 
    if( millis() - timer > 50 )
    {     
      mpu6050.update();
      Angle = mpu6050.getAngleZ();
      //Serial.println(Angle);
      timer = millis();
    }
    motorR.run(BACKWARD);
    motorL.run(FORWARD);
  }

  motorL.run(RELEASE); 
  motorR.run(RELEASE);

  if( dy == 1 )
  {
    dx = 1;
    dy = 0;
    Direction = 2;
  }
  else if( dy == -1 )
  {
    dx = -1;
    dy = 0;
    Direction = 4;
  }
  else if( dx == -1 )
  {
    dx = 0;
    dy = 1;
    Direction = 1;
  }
  else 
  {
    dx = 0;
    dy = -1;
    Direction = 3;
  }

  pingTimer[0] = millis();

  for (uint8_t i = 1; i < SONAR_NUM; i++) 
    pingTimer[i] = pingTimer[i - 1] + PING_INTERVAL;

}

void Turn180()
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SONAR_NUM; i++) 
    pingTimer[i] = -1;
  mpu6050.update();
  motorR.setSpeed(158);
  motorL.setSpeed(174);
  Angle = mpu6050.getAngleZ();
  NewAngle = Angle + 173.0;
  //Serial.println(Angle);
  //Serial.println(NewAngle);

  while(abs(Angle - NewAngle) > eps)
  { 
    if( millis() - timer > 50 )
    {     
        mpu6050.update();
        Angle = mpu6050.getAngleZ();
        //Serial.println(Angle);
        timer = millis();
    }

    motorR.run(FORWARD);
    motorL.run(BACKWARD);

  }

  motorL.run(RELEASE); 
  motorR.run(RELEASE);

  if (dy == 1)
  {
    dx = 0;
    dy = -1;
    Direction = 3;
  }
  else if (dy == -1)
  {
    dx = 0;
    dy = 1;
    Direction = 1;
  }
  else if (dx == 1)
  {
    dx = -1;
    dy = 0;
    Direction = 4;
  }
  else if (dx == -1)
  {
    dx = 1;
    dy = 0;
    Direction = 2;
  }

  pingTimer[0] = millis();

  for (uint8_t i = 1; i < SONAR_NUM; i++) 
    pingTimer[i] = pingTimer[i - 1] + PING_INTERVAL;
}

void Forward()
{
  motorL.setSpeed(92);
  motorR.setSpeed(85);

  motorL.run(FORWARD);
  motorR.run(FORWARD);
}


void Obstacles()
{
  if (WallLeft)
  {
    Map[x][y].Left = true;
  }
  else
  {
    Map[x][y].Left = false;
  }

  if (WallRight)
  {
    Map[x][y].Right = true;
  }
  else 
  {
    Map[x][y].Right = false;
  }

  if (WallFront)
  {
    Map[x][y].Front = true;
    Map[x][y].Back = false;
  }
  else 
  { 
    Map[x][y].Front = false;
    Map[x][y].Back = false;
  }

  Map[x][y].StrucDirection = Direction;

  Serial.print(" x:");
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print(" y:");
  Serial.print(y);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(Map[x][y].Left);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(Map[x][y].Right);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(Map[x][y].Front);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(Map[x][y].Back);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(Map[x][y].StrucDirection);
  Serial.print(" ");
}

void echoCheck() 
{
  if ( sonar[currentSensor].check_timer() ) 
  {
    cm[currentSensor] = sonar[currentSensor].ping_result / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM;

    pingResult( currentSensor );
  }
}

void pingResult( uint8_t sensor ) 
{ 
  modulo = cm[2] % 30;
  //Serial.print("Pravy: ");
  //Serial.println(cm[1]);
  //Serial.print("Predni: ");
  //Serial.println(cm[2]);

  if (cm[0] > 13)
  {
    WallLeft = false;
    //Serial.println("Vlevo neni prekazka");
  }
  else if (cm[0] <= 13)
  {
    WallLeft = true;
    //Serial.println("Vlevo je prekazka");
  } 

  if(cm[1] > 13)
  {
    WallRight = false;
    //Serial.println(cm[1]);
    //Serial.println("Vpravo neni prekazka");
  }
  else if (cm[1] <= 13){
    WallRight = true;
    //Serial.println(cm[1]);
    //Serial.println("Vpravo je prekazka");
  }

  if(cm[2] > 13)
  { 
    WallFront = false;
    WallBack = false;
  }
  else if (cm[2] <= 13)
  {
    WallFront = true;   
  }

}


void DecideWhereNext()
{

  if(!Map[x][y].Front && Map[x][y].Right )
  {
    Serial.println("Forward");
    Forward();

  }
  else if(!Map[x][y].Front && !Map[x][y].Left && Map[x][y].Right)
  {
    Serial.println("Forward");
    Forward();
  }
  else if(!Map[x][y].Front && !Map[x][y].Right)
  {
    Serial.println("Right");
    TurnRight();
    Forward();

  }
  else if(Map[x][y].Front && Map[x][y].Right && !Map[x][y].Left)
  {
    TurnLeft();
    Serial.println("Left");
    Forward();
  }
  else if (Map[x][y].Front && Map[x][y].Right && !Map[x][y].Left)
  {
    Turn180();
    Serial.println("Turning 180");
    Forward();
  }

}
```

I'm using the NewPing library also and I tried to stop the pings of the sensors while the robot is turning with the following code:

```
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SONAR_NUM; i++) 
  pingTimer[i] = -1;
```

and start pings again with:

```
pingTimer[0] = millis(); 
for (uint8_t i = 1; i < SONAR_NUM; i++) 
  pingTimer[i] = pingTimer[i - 1] + PING_INTERVAL;
```

as it was documented [here](https://bitbucket.org/teckel12/arduino-new-ping/wiki/Help%20with%2015%20Sensors%20Example%20Sketch).

I did not manage to start the pings again, so if anyone would be so kind and helped me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: what does this mean? `I tried to stop the sensors` ............. this is a very poor description of the observed behavior `without any success` .... please describe what actually happens

Comment: please add information to your question ... `please do not use comments`